# Get post request on the server and convert it to json

Tags: c++, json, qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

This is a simple Qt C++ HTTP server.

When i try to send a post request i see the next output

> "POST /?test=23&someKey=42 HTTP/1.1"

How can i convert this to json?

```
tcpServer = new QTcpServer();
if (!tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 2323)) {
    qDebug() << "ERROR: " << tcpServer->errorString();
    return;
}
qDebug() << "Ip: " << tcpServer->serverAddress();
qDebug() << "Port: " << tcpServer->serverPort();

QObject::connect(tcpServer, &QTcpServer::newConnection, [=]() {
    QTcpSocket *clientSocket = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
    QObject::connect(clientSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, [=]() {
        qDebug() << clientSocket->readLine();

    });
});
```

Comment: Your title, your code and your output have nothing to with the question you post. Please see [mcve] when posting code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert QMap to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484007/convert-qmap-to-json)